# Recommended way to initialize a new in-memory Realm based off a default Realm

Tags: realm

When creating a new in-memory Realm like this:

`let realm = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(inMemoryIdentifier: "MyInMemoryRealm"))`

it starts off empty. What is the recommended way to then initialize it with data from the default Realm?

Answer (score 0):

There is so far no built-in way to achieve something like that easily for the complete Realm. But you can open the default Realm independently and then copy the objects manually you want to share to the in-memory Realm.

```
let inMemoryRealm = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(inMemoryIdentifier: "MyInMemoryRealm"))
let defaultRealm = try! Realm()
for obj in defaultRealm.objects(FooObject) {
    inMemoryRealm.create(obj)
    // For objects with primary keys
    //inMemoryRealm.create(obj, update: true)
}
```

You will need to take extra care with copying objects which don't have primary keys themselves, but whose related objects have primary keys.